# Getting empty PDF while downloading through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

I am trying to download pdf file through JavaScript / jQuery. My code is:

```
function ShouldGeneratePdf() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Report/EmployeeReport",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    EmployeeId: $('#EmployeeId').val()
                },
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    //Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });

                    //Check the Browser type and download the File.
                    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                    if (isIE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                    } else {
                        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var a = $("<a />");
                        a.attr("download", "testFile.pdf");
                        a.attr("href", link);
                        $("body").append(a);
                        a[0].click();
                        $("body").remove(a);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        }
```

Above method does download the pdf but the downloaded file is empty.
Any idea what i am doing wrong ? Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: PDF file also includes images.

Answer (score 2):

After a very frustrating week trying to figure out how to solve this problem, I can suggest you to check this four basic points:

1.- Check if the Server's [CORS policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) is open to your site requests if you're using a subdomain or a completely different domain. This depends on your service type (mine was ASP.NET MVC).

2.- I had a conflict with my Web App and my Web API (since I didn't use ASP.NET Core from the very first time), so I couldn't use my `fetch` function normally, but if is not your case, try to use the `fetch API` from your client [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313196/2986652) because it can expect **the blob type directly from the request** (you can also try to use the [Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230807/2986652) or the [XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36474105/2986652) approach).

3.- (MOST IMPORTANT) What finally worked for me was to convert to Base64 the file [from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110009/2986652) BEFORE sending the response file and then [decode it from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669785/2986652) with a function. Skipping this step only threw a blank PDF even when I could preview it from the Safari inspector and had a perfectly PDF response with all its bytes, but this wasn't enough for the browser to download it correctly; so try to encode it first.

4.- Finally remember to define the Data type and Content type that best suits your needs in your request. In my case:

```
...
dataType: 'text',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
success: function(response) {
...
```